# Subquery - SQL SERVER: Clean carriage returns, spaces, and re-order

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I currently have the following script to remove carriage returns and extra spacing:

```
REVERSE(
        STUFF(
            REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM((REPLACE((LTRIM(V_CTX_BASIC_INFO.CUSTOM_3)),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),','))
))), 
            1, 
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING((REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM((REPLACE((LTRIM(V_CTX_BASIC_INFO.CUSTOM_3)),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),','))
)))), 1, 1) = ',' THEN 1 WHEN SUBSTRING((REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM((REPLACE((LTRIM(V_CTX_BASIC_INFO.CUSTOM_3)),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),','))
)))), 1, 1) = ',,' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END, 
            ''
        )
    ))
```

The data in the field is either 9 digits with a dash or 9 straight digits (##-####### or #########) and is comma separated, comma space separated, or carriage return separated.

I am trying to add an ORDER BY to the subquery above to order by ascending

I am limited to write this into a single subquery.

Comment: You cant order by in a subquery. It would be worth posting your actual query.

Comment: Thanks Tom - unfortunately the program I am writing this in doesn't allow the entire query to be changed.  I can only create a subquery on a single calculated formula entry.  I appreciate the response.